# Can we move a post from my wall to my Group wall?

Tags: facebook

I made a group named 'X-factor' where I added my very close friends, so that only they can see, post and comment there. Sometimes we forget to write something on that wall and started commenting below that and our family members are also in our friend list.

Is there any way to move any status/photo from main wall to 'X-factor' group wall ... like we move one photo from one album to another?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not currently possible within Facebook UI.